# Reminder for recuring calendar events with mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, momentjs, rrule, node-cron

I want to send notifications/reminders to my users, the reminder schema is basically like this

```
{
    user: 'number',
    time: {   //this is the time the event will occur
        type: Date,
        index: true
    },
    reminder: Number, //the number of minutes that user wants to be reminded before events occur
    date_reminder: { //this is basicaly time - reminder, 
        type: Date,
        index: true
    },
    text: String,
    eventId: Number,
    rrule: String, //the recurrence rrulle
    until: { //the date that the reccurence will end
        type: Date
    },
    title_event: String,
    calendarId: Number,
});
```

So I made a Cron Job to search in mongodb every minute for reminders that match this query:

```
{
    $or: [{
        rrule: {
            $ne: ""
        },
        $or: [{
            until: null //if until === null, its repeat forever
        }, {
            until: {
                $gte: new Date()
            }
        }],
    }, {
        date_reminder: new Date()
    }]
}
```

Then for every reminder that this query returns I need to check if the date generated with its `rrule` minus its `reminder` matches `new Date()`

```
let now = new Date();
let remindersToSend = [];
reminders.forEach(reminder => {
    if (reminder.rrule === "") {
        //ts just a normal reminder that its date_reminder matches now 
        remindersToSend.push(reminder);
    } else {
        //this is a reccuring reminder, i need to check if some of its reccuring reminders matches now
        let myrrule = rrule.rrulestr(reminder.rrule);
        let repeatedReminders = myrrule.between(reminder.time, now);
        for (let i = 0; i < repeatedReminders.length; i++) {
            if (Math.round(moment.duration(moment(repeatedReminders[i])
                    .diff(moment(now))
                ).asMinutes()) === reminder.reminder) {
                //this repeatedDate matches now;
                remindersToSend.push(reminder);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
})
```

Then, after all this, I can safely send notifications  to all `remindersToSend` but this is giving me a crappy performance as i repeat this every minute, I don't know how I can make a better mongo query to get rid of reminders that none of its recurrence time matches `now`

Answer (score 2):

You could once per hour/day pre-calculate all the upcoming occurrences for each rrule that will occur in the next hour/day.
Store those in the database with your reminders. 
Then each minute you would only need to query for reminders that have a pre-calculated occurrence in the current minute.
Depending on your use-case you may even be able to pre-calculate all of the occurrences of your reminders.

Comment: Good suggestion, damn, I made this question 3 months ago, and i forgot to update it with my approach, what I did was  create a new worker thread in node.js exclusive to handling this specific cron-job, so basically, every minute i create a new worker thread and delete it after it done its job.